# How do you map input to multiple replacement values with a regular expression for C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have two input values:

**apple**

**carrot**

I would like to find a regular expression I can use with a C# program using Regex.Replace() to recognize these inputs and replace them with unrelated values. I do not have a chance to change the code. I can only provide the input, pattern, and replacement parameters.

For example:

If **apple** is found, replace with **fruit**

If **carrot** is found, replace with **vegetable**

I can match them easily with **^apple|tomato$** but I see no way to make the substitution I want. The only options for replacement seem to be something from the input or a singular fixed value.

Comment: What method signatures of Regex.Replace do you have access to? Do you have access to this one: public static string Replace(
 string input,
 string pattern,
 MatchEvaluator evaluator
)

Comment: No, we are not using _MatchEvaluator_. My only option is to provide the regular expression and replacement strings in a configuration file and was hoping some regex magic was there to allow me to avoid modifying the product code and inventing some way of describing this configuration. Seems like something we will need to add in the next version.

Answer (score 2):

There is, unfortunately, no way to do that with a single RegEx replacement.  There is no way to alter the value of a capturing group in the pattern itself, or "hard-code" the value of a group in the pattern.

If, however, the application allows you to provide multiple pattern/replacement pairs which will be executed in succession, then you could do it by providing to pairs:

- Pair 1

  - Pattern: `^apple$`
  - Replacement: `fruit`
- Pair 2

  - Pattern: `^tomato$`
  - Replacement: `vegetable`

Answer (score 0):

It's no matter with Regex,it's mapping,you can finish it like below

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    {"fruit",new List<string>{"apple","orange"}},
    {"vegetable",new List<string>{"carrot"}}
};
Func<string, string> func = (inputStr) =>
{
    var query = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Any(y => string.Equals(y, inputStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
    return query.Key;
};
Console.WriteLine(func("apple"));
Console.WriteLine(func("carrot"));
Console.WriteLine(func("nothing")==null);
```